# Is this a valid model specification?

Tags: regression, time-series, arima, model, misspecification

I am working with weekly, highly seasonal data (period=52) and fitting the following regression using `lm`:
$$
y_t=\rho_1y_{t-1}+\rho_2y_{t-52}+\beta x_t+\varepsilon_t
$$
where $x_t$ is a vector of independent variables that are also highly seasonal.

This isn't exactly a type of model I have seen before but it produces a good fit ($R^2=.8$) and fairly accurate forecasts. Is there a reason why this would not work or is there a better way to model this?(I am aware that working with weekly data like this is difficult because a year does not have exactly 52 weeks but since the seasonality is annual, it should not be a huge issue.)

Comment: 52 vs. 52.18 should not be a big issue for 10 or 20 years, but if your time span is much longer than that, it could make a difference.

Comment: @RichardHardy but other than that I'm not running into any nasty misspecification problems, am I? I know it's not exactly an elegant model but it works just fine

Comment: I find the model pretty elegant! However, I wonder if the seasonality in $x_t$ should be somehow accounted for (either within the model or by seasonally adjusting $x_t$ before putting it into the model), as otherwise it would tend to make the residuals seasonal.

Comment: @RichardHardy Thank you! I seasonally adjusted $x_t$ and now I'm at $R^2=.87$. That worked wonderfully!

Comment: @RichardHardy If you turned that into an answer, I would vote it up :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the seasonality in $x_t$ should be accounted for, as otherwise it would tend to make the residuals seasonal. You could seasonally adjust $x_t$ before putting it into the model or include some seasonal terms (e.g. Fourier terms) in the model.

Side note: 52 vs. 52.18 weeks a year should not be a big issue for 10 or 20 years, but if your time span is much longer than that, it could make a difference.